# How do you add a static option to a webform?

Tags: webform-civicrm

I am trying to update our webform to add an upcoming event to our registration page (static options)  I don't want to save over the past events because I believe that will override the existing data (and I can't seem to figure out how to save over it in any case)

For example, we've had a series of events every month this year and I am trying to add the event for next month without saving over the past several events.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE!

The way to do this is to add an Event for each Event in your CiviCRM - and then to select the current one on your say October Event Webform;

You can use node clone module to clone the webform to say November Event Webform;